# Joomla! 3 : list articles from multiple categories

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I want to list all articles from multiple categories in a single page. I don't need the category name. But, I want all the articles from the category be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to

> Module manager

Create new module type:

> Module Articles Category

Now you can select many category or all category in `Filtering Options` tab.

In `Category Filtering Type` option, put this to `Inclusive`

Then put that module on an article and link this article to menu item.

For put module on an article, you can use:

```
{loadposition myPosition} // add by module position
```

or

```
{loadmodule myModule} // add by module name
```

Comment: Thanks ..That really helps.